# Combinations in board game, l:=landscapes, q:=folks and k:= Player

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Combinations in board game, l:=landscapes, q:=folks and k:= Player
So I have struggle with this one and didn't find a similar situation. Do you have any clue on the way to solve this?

The game has l differend landscapes. In each lanscapes are q folks. At the start every player chooses a folk, where landscapes are unique.

How many different start configurations are there with k players if:

-Only the combination of folks is relevant?

Here I already have struggle because I didn't found a similar situation with a solution.

With l Landscapes and q folks I would have (l choose q) ? But it seems like each Landscape has it's own q folks.

And how do I now take the player k in account?

I guess I have to divide the space of combinations by k? Right?

My try is: $\frac{l!*q}{k}$

-If it's relevant which player plays which folk

And here multiplying by k! ?

Thanks for any help to get a better understanding

Comment: So each player choses a folk within a landscape, and no landscape has two players active in it? is that how it works?

Comment: Yes as far as I understood it right! Would my equation be right this way?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that for $\ell$ landsacpes, each containing $q$ folk, each of the $k$ players choses a folk within a landscape but all players choose different landscapes...

Since the first question is looking for the options of folk choice, without distinguishing which player chose which, we can pick landscapes with $\dbinom \ell k$ and then the choice of folk in each landscape is entirely independent, so $q^k$ options once the landscapes are chosen. Together: $\dbinom \ell k q^k$

Finally if the allocation of players to folk is discriminated, we can (as you say) permute the players across each anonymous selection with an additional factor of $k!$.

Comment: Well the l choose k part is quite obvious now. Thanks even the q factorized by k. Thanks. Tried for hours to get your solution. I hope it will become easier with time.

Comment: So if the players are relevant we permute in the k in the binomial right? So replacing k with k! ? And in the factor as well.

Comment: No, you just multiply the whole previous expression by $k!$